# Java Google Contacts API Access Service Account Authentication

Tags: java, google-api, authorization, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to access [Googles Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) but my attempt failed already on getting authorized. From other (web) languages i'm used to the APIConsole and the public API-key (authorization).

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken("<<PublicAPIKey>>");
System.out.println(credential.refreshToken());          // false
```

This way I'm not able to refresh the token and be unsure about using the public-key as [accesstoken](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#googlecredential)... Instead I tried over a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwtsample_java):

```
private static final String USER_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xy@gmail.com";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xy@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "xy.p12";

public App() {
    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
    scopes.add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds");

    try {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountUser(USER_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();

        System.out.println(credential.refreshToken());
        //System.out.println(credential.getAccessToken());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here my exception:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
        at App.<init>(App.java:50)
        at App.main(App.java:29)
```

Thanks for a hint!

Comment: Are you sure that a service account has contacts?

Comment: Not really but [over oauth1 like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407415/accessing-google-contacts-api-via-oauth-2-0-and-private-key-aka-service-account) isn't an alternative - it closes down in 6 days... and I dont get the mechanism  over the public API access.

Comment: Worst workaround ever: If I made a request to another API e.g Google Plus, the first Request returns a valid access-token. From there on I can access over the `setOAuth2Credentials()` to the Contacts API. Not amused :)

Comment: Post that as an answer.   I love hacks might be useful someday.   Background:  contacts API is an old gdata API, very basic and a pain.   Google plus is a discovery API and much easer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without calling `setServiceAccountUser()` my code just worked perfectly fine. But you just will have an [impersonated account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder#setServiceAccountUser(java.lang.String)) (service_account_mail) not your personal contacts.

Another possible source for a "401 Unauthorized" exception is leaving the `credential.refreshToken()` away. The call is necessary to write the access-code into the  reference.

Below the finished class:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Connector {

  private static ContactsService contactService = null;
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Your-App/1.0";
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xy@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

  private Connector() {
    // explicit private no-args constructor
  }

  public static ContactsService getInstance() {
    if (contactService == null) {
      try {
        contactService = connect();

      } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return contactService;
  }

  private static ContactsService connect() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    // @formatter:off
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                            .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                            .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                                            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                                            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"))
                                            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
                                            .build();
    // @formatter:on

    if (!credential.refreshToken()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed OAuth to refresh the token");
    }

    ContactsService myService = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
    myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    return myService;
  }

}
```

Comment: but what if you wanted the personal account instead of the service account?

Comment: Hey @StephanCelis

Try this as an **untested** assumption how the api works with personal accounts. Replace the connect function with this:
`private static ContactsService connect(String uname, String pw) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  contactService = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
  try {
    contactService.setUserCredentials(uname, pw);
  } catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
  }
  return myService;
}`
Don't forget to enable [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).